# Web Kit Transitions Left functionality not working -- Solve a Fiddle

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, css-transitions

I'm having enormous trouble with the position:relative element in webkit transition to move it to the left.   It should work but does not. A class is added via jQuery that should then take effect.

```
<div id="reviews">
    <div id="dropout">Blast</div>

    <a href="#" onclick="dropout(); return false">move it</a>
</div>

#reviews #dropout {
    position:relative;
    min-height:40px;
    left:40px;
    -webkit-transition: left 600ms;
    -moz-transition: left 600ms;
}
#reviews .dropopen {
    min-height:40px;
    left:0px;
    -webkit-transition: left 600ms;
    -moz-transition: left 600ms;
}

function dropout() {
    $('#dropout').addClass('dropopen');
}
```

Perhaps a Fiddle might help http://jsfiddle.net/4WmJz/1/

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: haha, "Solve a Fiddle" - I like it. Sounds like a good website idea.

Comment: Seems link the function is never called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Solved](http://jsfiddle.net/4WmJz/11/)! (I hope)

There were a couple of problems. Firstly the `onclick()` function was not bound correctly, jQuery was not loaded on the jsFiddle page and most importantly, the specificity of your selectors was wrong. Basically `#id #id` selector has a greater specificity than `#id .class`, so even if the class was correctly added to the element, the properties would not be applied.

**Edit** Another occasion to link to a [great visualization of CSS specificity](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg).